# Find the first moment that a column meets a condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to find the number of the row that data in the columns reached a certain value.

Data:

```
Data = data.frame(    Time = seq(1,5),
                    V1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9),
                    v2 = c(0.1, 0.12, 0.41, 0.72, 0.91),
                    v3 = c(0.03, 0.13, 0.62, 0.50, 0.90))
```

Desired result: (First Time In 0.6)

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  4  4  3
```

Comment: should not it be 4 for V3?

Comment: There may be a simpler way but `apply(Data[, -1], 2, function(x) head(which(x >= .6), 1))` does it recognizing that for column 3 the answer is 3 not 5.

Comment: yeah, youre right. it should be 3. i will try this solution

Answer (score 3):

We can use **dplyr** with `summarise` and `first(which(condition))`

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>% summarise(across(-Time, ~first(which(.x>0.6))))

  V1 v2 v3
1  4  4  3
```

Or with **base R:**

```
data.frame(lapply(Data[-1], \(x) first(which(x>0.6))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R:

Use `which` to find the indices of rows that satisfy your condition and `min` to find the lowest (i.e., first) of these indices. Also use `lapply` to apply it multiple columns like so:

```
data.frame(lapply(Data[c("V1", "v2", "v3")], function(x) min(which(x > 0.6))))
```